# VOIP for Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, voip

I'm looking for a good voice over ip program to make phone calls using Ubuntu. Can you help me?

I only need the basic functionality i.e. **voice** (sound, audio) and not everything else. I don't require profiles, chat, account management, business vs personal accounts or so.

I only want a good basic functionality that also has good availability.

My geographic location is northern Europe (Stockholm), if that matters. I could be satisfied even with local calls only within Stockholm since that is my **common case**.

My preferences are, in descending order:

Low price or free of charge, quality of sound, lag, user-friendliness, community.

Price is the most important in this case since otherwise I might just use my regular cellphone.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. What features do you need (e.g. voice calls, video calls, chat, registering the `tel://` protocoll so you can even click corresponding URLs in the browser to initialte calls…)? Some VoIP supporting software even comes pre-installed on most sytems (Ekiga, Pidgin).

Comment: There are many VOIP tools for Ubuntu. Please sort these in your order of priority: Quality of sound, lag, user-friendliness, community, price. Also, do you need group calls? Please edit your question then ask us to reopen.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I only need a good basic function and I can even be happy with local calls only. Naturally I mean the common case. My common case is a local phonecall with voice only and only between me and exactly one other phone number. I want the program to be able to call a number that is not registered with the VOIP provider. Example: From the program I should be able to call +46 (0) 8 753 25 xx where that number is not even connected to the VOIP provider. I want this as simple as making a local *normal* phone call from my computer.

Comment: Please edit your question and write these in your order of priority: Quality of sound, lag, user-friendliness, community, price.